# Can i install Broadcom wifi driver offline?

Tags: settings, wifi, networking, drivers

I am newbue at Elementary but also have some experience in Ubuntu. 
I recently installed elementary, but wifi did not configure automatically. I have no way to connect my computer to the Internet via wire. How do I configure wifi offline? Or where and which drivers to download to solve this problem?

```
Broadcom 14e4:4365 rev 01
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of lsusb is not enough to understand the exact model of the wifi card. For more details try

```
lsusb -v
```

or

```
lshw
```

Then, take a look at my answer [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24083/cant-find-wireless-wifi-setting-in-hera/24086#24086)
Basically if the system detected the wifi card but needs proprietary drivers to work, you should see the suggestion in the appcenter

Otherwise, when you have the exact model just google for the drivers