# Can't find wireless wifi setting in Hera

Tags: wifi, release-hera

[image]

I don't see the wireless wifi setting after installing. Am i missing any drivers?[image]

here's my usb list.. what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no separate network manager module for wifi, so I can exclude the case you are missing some piece of nm.

Next, I assume your wifi card is the Realtek one. If this is the case, it's good because, at least, it's been detected.

If this is the case, try to install ubuntu-drivers-common, which is a gui to help you install proprietary drivers (if I remember correctly it's not installed by default).

Just type

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

After having installed this basically if you go into the installed applications in the app store you'll see that it will suggest you to install some proprietary drivers

[image: see attached screenshot].

Another check you can do is if this wifi card is enabled; you can perform this check through rfkill

`rfkill list`

and if the wireless card is blocked/turned off just type

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Of course, if the realtek device that appears in your lsusb is not the wireless card, this could means that it was not been even detected

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Asus ZenBook (just shipped) with an Intel 9000 series wireless adapter built in, and I had the same problem. I solved it by manually installing the backport of iwlwifi using the advice of "jeremy31" here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi

Note that the first recommended install didn't solve my problem; it was the second step (getting the newer version from Canonical) that actually solved my problem.